# Is Windows Home and Windows Home Single Language is same edition?

Tags: windows, language, windows-activation

I have a product key for `windows 8.1` (Single language edition or not that i can't remember). I have currently windows 10 pro installed.

I am planning to install windows 10 Home so i activate with windows 8.1 key.

So my question is will i be able to activate it if the Product Key is `Windows 8.1 Single Language` and i install `Windows 10 Home`(Multiple language edition) or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/windows10), the `Windows 8/8.1 Single Language` or 
`Windows 8 Single Language with Bing` get updated to `Windows 10 Home Single Language`.

So it looks like you can't use the Single Language key in the normal multi language edition.