# Can I use my windows 10 home single language key for multi language windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10

I am currently using windows 10 home single language as a direct updrade from windows 8(not 8.1), i had to refresh as my display drivers didn't work along with other things, but anyways can i use the key from single language to install multi language windows 10 home

Comment: If you could use a Single Language key to install a Home edition then it wouldn't be a Single Language key...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a single language key in multi language edition.

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1020980/is-windows-home-and-windows-home-single-language-is-same-edition) answer too.

Comment: oops, sorry for asking a duplicate question, seems I didn't read enough. Anyways thanks for answering my questions